# I need to find whether my Websphere servers are running on version 6 or version 8 currently?

Tags: websphere, was

I have got two versions installed in WebSphere Application Server ( version 6 and version 8 ).  I need to find whether my Websphere servers are active on version 6 or version 8 currently from backend ( UNIX ) ?

Please don't suggest ps -ef | grep java, because it does not show the processes of servers in case the servers are not running. I want a solution that works irrespective of whether servers is running or not.

Answer (score 2):

Both releases have `bin/bersionInfo.sh`  (or .bat on Windows).

Comment: The versionInfo.sh will be present in both v6 and v8 so it will not be able to give me the version where the servers are actually running. This will not be helping me I guess. I have got both the versions installed as mentioned in description.

Comment: It gives you the version if you execute it.  If you want to find a file that differs based on just existence, compare your filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

Consult `/properties/version/profile.version. Since you seem to know the location of the profile on disk but not whether it will be running or not, this file will indicate what version of WAS it was created by. Profiles can only be owned by the version of WebSphere they were created by, so this should be the version the profile will run with when started.

Comment: I guess the profile.version will be present in both v6 and v8 properties path so it will not be able to give me the version where the servers are actually running. This will not be helping me I guess. I have got both the versions installed as mentioned in description.

Comment: A profile can only be owned by one install of WAS at a time. It's profile.version will reflect the version of the install which owns it, regardless of where it is in the filesystem or what other installs of WAS may exist.

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue here that you know where the separate v6 and v8 installations are on the file system, but you simply want to know which of them is active?  If so, use the serverStatus.sh|bat script - call it against your WAS 6 server, then call it against your WAS 8 server, and you'll know which is active.

Alternately, you could use ps -ef|grep java and check the PID against the pid file in your server's logs directory.